# Get Address without the port .net and construct address + port to an endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, url, port

From a URL like "`http://localhost:2111/`" How to separate the address part : `http://localhost/` from the port part: 2111? Is there a data structure that allow me to separate or construct  `http://localhost:2111/` to/from its address and port?

Comment: Look at the `Uri` class.

Comment: @leppie It seems that I can't construct `http://localhost:2111/` from `http://localhost/` and 2111

Comment: @leppie `Port` is read only in Uri

Comment: Look at `UriBuilder` then :)

Comment: @leppie That works for me! You can make it an answer if you want :)

Comment: Add your solution as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:2111/");
string newUri = uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Host + "/";
Console.WriteLine(newUri);

// Output:
// http://localhost/
```

To do the opposite:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/");
string newURI = uri.AbsoluteUri + uri.Port;
```

For me `uri.Ports`returns `80`, I don't know if it works for you but give it a try.

Comment: What do you mean with "opposite"?

Answer (score 1):

[UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) can be used to remove the port from the url by setting its port value to either -1 or 80:

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:2111/");
uriBuilder.Port = -1;  // or 80
string newUrl = uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
Console.WriteLine(newUrl);
```

The above will output `http://localhost/`.

If you want to add them back together then use UriBuilder again and set the port to 2111:

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://localhost/");
uriBuilder.Port = 2111;
string newUrl = uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
Console.WriteLine(newUrl);
```

The above will output `http://localhost/2111`.